# Using CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning how to use CROSS JOINS and I can't see what I am doing wrong with the one I am currently attempting.

What I have is a `Pattern` and `Numbers` table.

**Number Table:**
Numberid TinyINT

**Pattern Table:**
PatternID TinyINT IDentity(1,1)
Patternresult varchar(5)

I have already inserted each row in the `Number` table from 1 - 22.

At the moment I am getting no results displayed. But what **I want to display is all the patterns between only numbers 0 - 5 (I can't include '0' in the number table as later on I will be using a table that requires a number beginning at '1' from the 'Number' table**

```
e.g

0 - 0
0 - 1
0 - 2
0 - 3
0 - 4
0 - 5
1 - 0
1 - 1
1 - 2
1 - 3
1 - 4
1 - 5

etc
```

What am I doing incorrectly with my CROSS JOIN?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern(PatternResult)
SELECT cast(n.NumberID AS VARCHAR (5)) + ' - ' + cast(nn.NumberID AS VARCHAR (5)) AS PatternResult
FROM dbo.Number n
CROSS JOIN dbo.Number nn
```

Comment: _I am getting no results displayed_, do you mean rows cannot be inserted into table `Pattern` ?

Comment: The cross join itself works - just saw the length of `PatternResult` in `dbo.Pattern` - it's too short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your query is an `insert`.  `Insert` statements do not return result sets.

So, the question is, what does this return?

```
select *
from dbo.Pattern
```

Next, the pattern has space for five characters, but you are already using up three with `' - '`.  So, try making it so the pattern can fit (by removing the spaces):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Pattern(PatternResult)
    SELECT cast(n.NumberID AS VARCHAR (5)) + '-' + cast(nn.NumberID AS VARCHAR (5)) AS PatternResult
    FROM dbo.Number n CROSS JOIN
         dbo.Number nn;
```

Finally, when using `VARCHAR()` there really is no advantage to making the sizes too small.  You might as well define the field as something like `Patternresult varchar(255)` so it will always be big enough for any result.  When using `CHAR()` then a small value is important, because all the extra characters are stored as spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.i have added ">0" in my query ,since i have numbers table starting from 0 ,you can ignore that..

```
    ;With Cte
    as
    (
    select 0 as n
    union all
    select top 5 Number from numbers where number>0
    order by number
    )
Insert into dbo.pattern
(
PatternResult
)
    select cast(c.n as varchar)+'-'+b.n
     from cte c
    cross join
    (select cast(n as varchar) from cte) b(n)
    order by c.n
```

**Output:**

```
0-0
0-1
0-2
0-3
0-4
0-5
1-0 and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

your problems your number contains number from 1 to 22 and the PatternResult is only varchar(5)

so when you concatenate a 2 digits number, you will get PatternResult like '12 - 13' , which the length exceeded 5

And so your query should get truncation error and hence no result in the Pattern table.

Change the PatternResult to varchar(10) and it should work.